# Expl3' tl variable storing the result of a \seq_map_inline: OK in article's title but not in beamer's title

Tags: beamer, expl3, token-lists

As pointed out by the following MCE, an `expl3`' token list variable storing the result of a `\seq_map_inline:` used in `\title`'s argument:

- works like a charm with the `article` class,
- doesn't work with the `beamer` class:

  ```
        ! Undefined control sequence.
        <argument> \LaTeX3 error: 
                                  A sequence was misused.
  ```

Do you know why and how to make it work with `beamer`'s class as well?

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_tmpa_seq { foo, bar }
\tl_set:Nn \g_tmpa_tl
{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_seq
  {
    #1,\c_space_tl
  }
}
\title{\g_tmpa_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

### Edit: aim that led me to the current question (and its simplified MCE)

For a course I'm giving, I prepare some presentations with the `beamer` class
(BTW, what follows could apply to any class). The content of the whole course is
splitted in several subjects (one file per subject) that are `\input`. The
subjects (titles)/corresponding files that may be treated are (say):

- "Foo 1"/`foo1.tex`
- "Foo 2"/`foo2.tex`
- "Foo 3"/`foo3.tex`
- "Foo 4"/`foo4.tex`
- "Foo 5"/`foo5.tex`

The presentations' contents (chosen subjects) varies depending on the audience
and/or on the course progress.

The point is, I want for a given presentation the chosen subjects' titles to
appear in the presentation's `\title`.

Suppose the current presentation is about "Foo 2" and "Foo 4". I could
do the following:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
...
\title{
  % Foo 1,
  Foo 2,
  % Foo 3,
  Foo 4
  % Foo 5,
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
% \input{foo1}
\input{foo2}
% \input{foo3}
\input{foo4}
% \input{foo5}
\end{document}
```

but this way of doing is painful and error prone: whenever the list of
`\input`ed files changes, I have to (not forget to) change the `\title`'s
content.

Note having the subjects' titles in the corresponding files is useless: they
would be too late read to be in the presentation's `\title` (okay, another way of
doing would be to write them in the `.aux` file and read them at the next
compilation when the `\title` has to be filled, but that's another story).

So, what I am aiming, is to have :

- a fixed **property list** (say `\g_subjects_prop`) containing the whole list
  of the subjects with, for each of them:

  - as key: the name of the corresponding file,
  - as value: its title.
    This list could be populated in a config file thanks to a document command
    (say `SubjectFileTitle{⟨filename⟩}{⟨title⟩}`),
- a **sequence** (say `\g_chosen_subjects_seq`) containing the keys of the
  chosen subjects. This sequence could be populated in the preamble thanks to
  a document command (say `ChosenSubjects{⟨comma separated list of keys
  (files)⟩}`),
- a token list (say `\g_title_tl`, instead of `\l_tmpa_tl`(?)) containing the values corresponding to the
  chosen keys above to be passed as `\title`'s argument,
- a document command (say `\InputChosenSubjects`) which, where used, inserts the
  sequence of the `\input`ed chosen files.

Thanks to egreg's answer, I managed with the following code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{foo2}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo 2 subject: quite interesting!}
  ...
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_subjects_prop
\seq_new:N \g_chosen_subjects_seq
\tl_new:N \g_title_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\SubjectFileTitle}{mm}
{
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_subjects_prop {#1} {#2}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__chosen_subjects:n #1
{
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_chosen_subjects_seq {
    #1
  }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_chosen_subjects_seq
  {
    \prop_get:NnN \g_subjects_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_tl {
      \seq_put_right:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {\prop_item:Nn \g_subjects_prop {##1}}
    }
  }
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_title_tl
  {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {,~}
  }
  \title{\g_title_tl}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\ChosenSubjects}{m}
{
  \__chosen_subjects:n {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__input_chosen_subjects_files:
{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_chosen_subjects_seq
  {
    \par
    \file_if_exist_input:nF {##1}{%
      \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\alert{File~\texttt{##1.tex}~not~found!}}
      \end{frame}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\InputChosenSubjects}{}{
  \__input_chosen_subjects_files:
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\SubjectFileTitle{foo1}{Foo 1}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo2}{Foo 2}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo3}{Foo 3}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo4}{Foo 4}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo5}{Foo 5}

\ChosenSubjects{
  % foo1,
  foo2,
  % foo3,
  foo4,
  % foo5,
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\InputChosenSubjects
\end{document}
```

Comment: In beamer the title argument is being stored in `\inserttitle`, but that value is also being fed to `\hypersetup{pdftitle={...}` could that be the culprit? Emulating storing in a macro and using it, does not seem to cause problems, but I haven't tested hypersetup

Comment: It **IS** a hyperref error, in a article variant add hyperref and `\newcommand\test[1]{\def\inserttest{#1}}\test{\g_tmpa_tl}` and try `\hypersetup{pdftitle=\inserttest}`, this gies the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking TeX do perform `\seq_map_inline:Nn` while processing `\maketitle`. More likely, you want `\maketitle` to print the list of words separated by “comma and space”. In order to do this, use `\tl_gset:Nx` and `\seq_use:Nn`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_tmpa_seq { foo, bar }
\tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl
{
  \seq_use:Nn \g_tmpa_seq {,~}
}
\exp_args:NV \title \g_tmpa_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I'd note that `\g_tmpa_tl` is not the proper variable to use, but I believe it is just for the sake of the example.

---

Here's an edited version of your code. I renamed functions and variables giving a common prefix. Most importantly, I fixed a glitch: if a property doesn't exist in a `prop` variable, then

```
\prop_get:NnN <prop variable> {<property>} <tl variable>
```

sets the token list variable to `\q_no_value`, rather than to “empty”. So the test to use is `\quark_if_no_value:NF`.

Also, instead of calling `\title{\g_pres_title_tl}`, I'd prefer

```
\exp_args:NV \title \g_pres_title_tl
```

so the contents of the variable is passed to `\title`, rather than the container.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{foo2}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Foo 2 subject: quite interesting!}
  ...
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

%% variables
\prop_new:N \g_pres_subjects_prop
\seq_new:N \g_pres_subjects_chosen_seq
\tl_new:N \g_pres_title_tl

%% User level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\SubjectFileTitle}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_pres_subjects_prop {#1} {#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\ChosenSubjects}{m}
 {
  \pres_subjects_choose:n {#1}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\InputChosenSubjects}{}
 {
  \pres_input_chosen_subjects_files:
 }

%% functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pres_subjects_choose:n #1
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_pres_subjects_chosen_seq { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_pres_subjects_chosen_seq
   {
    \prop_get:NnN \g_pres_subjects_prop {##1} \l_tmpa_tl
    \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_tmpa_tl
     {
      \seq_put_right:NV \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
     }
   }
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_pres_title_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,~}
   }
  \exp_args:NV \title \g_pres_title_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pres_input_chosen_subjects_files:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_pres_subjects_chosen_seq
   {
    \par
    \file_if_exist_input:nF {##1}
     {
      \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{\alert{File~\texttt{##1.tex}~not~found!}}
      \end{frame}
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\SubjectFileTitle{foo1}{Foo 1}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo2}{Foo 2}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo3}{Foo 3}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo4}{Foo 4}
\SubjectFileTitle{foo5}{Foo 5}

\ChosenSubjects{
  % foo1,
  foo2,
  % foo3,
  foo4,
  % foo5,
  blurb % this doesn't exist among the defined files
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
\InputChosenSubjects
\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, I wanted "TeX to perform `\seq_map_inline:Nn` while processing `\maketitle`": I'm a bit lost about what is possible and what is not in `expl3` :) About `\g_tmpa_tl`: what would you advise instead?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I can't understand from the example code what your aim is.

Comment: I detailed my aim in the question.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added an edited version.

Comment: Many thanks for the 2 improvements! But could you elaborate: as my code did work, I don't see the points of the important glitch and of the preferred `\exp_args:NV \title \g_pres_title_tl`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Try with `blurb` as in my code.

Comment: Ah, now I see :)

Answer (score 2):

Too long for comment, this gives the same error without beamer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_tmpa_seq { foo, bar }
\tl_set:Nn \g_tmpa_tl
{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_seq
  {
    #1,\c_space_tl
  }
}

\newcommand\test[1]{
  \def\inserttest{#1}
}
\test{\g_tmpa_tl}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
%\maketitle

\hypersetup{pdftitle=\inserttest}

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good catch! Now, isn't it "normal" since, following egreg's advise, that works with `\seq_use:Nn` instead of `\seq_map_inline:Nn`.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé isn't the issue that egregs solution is fully expandable where as yours is not (I can never understand the various ltx3 macros). Though, not at all sure why we get that particular error? We know that hyperref does a lot of parsing of the PDF data it uses.

Answer (score 2):

beamer issues (in beamerbasetitle.sty)

```
\hypersetup{pdftitle={\inserttitle\ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\ - \insertsubtitle\fi}}
```

This means that \inserttitle should be something that hyperref can handle in a bookmark -- when expl3 commands are involved: Stick to commands with a star in the documentation.

You can avoid that beamer uses the title as pdftitle by using

```
\documentclass[usepdftitle=false,hyperref={pdftitle=somethingsafe}]{beamer}
```

This will also affect author pdf-fields, so they would need to be set manually too.