# expl3-strategy to automatically update the title of a document, depending on its content

Tags: expl3, input, automation, auxiliary-files

### Context

The current question arises:

- as an attempt to improve the aim explained in a question of mine
  ([Expl3' tl variable storing the result of a \seq_map_inline: OK in article's title but not in beamer's title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/489560/18401)),
- in order to explain why using `\exp_not:N` instead of `\exp_not:V`, as
  suggested by egreg in his answer of another question of mine
  ([\TeX and \LaTeX differently expl3-x-written (exhaustive expansion) to an auxiliary file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/490125/18401)), is useless in my use case.

### Aim (sum up)

I have a main (`beamer`) document, say `main.tex`, the content of which varying,
depending on the targeted audience. For this, `main.tex` inputs one or more of,
say, 5 child files: `topic1.tex`, `topic2.tex`, `topic3.tex`, `topic4.tex`,
`topic5.tex`.

Each topic (file) has a topic title and I want the title of the main document to
automatically be the list of the titles of the topics that are input (and only
the ones that are input).

For this, I used the following strategy:

- At the beginning of each topic file, the topic title is specified, thanks to
  a `\topictitle` macro.
- Each time it is used, this macro appends the corresponding topic title to the
  right of a `\g_topics_seq` sequence.
- At the end of the (main) document:

  - the content of `\g_topics_seq` sequence is placed in
    a `\g_presentation_title_tl` token list,
  - the (not expanded: `\exp_not:V`) content of `\g_presentation_title_tl` is
    `x`-written to an auxiliary `.sbj` file.
- At the end of the preamble of the (main) document (hence at the next
  compilation):

  - a scratch token list is `x`-set to contain the content of the auxiliary
    file,
  - the content of this scratch token list is passed to `\title`.

The following MCE is the implementation of this strategy but I wonder if `expl3`
could provide a better one.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic1}
\topictitle{% \TeX{},
 \LaTeX{} and café%
}
\begin{frame}
  \TeX{}, \LaTeX{} and café are nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic2}
\topictitle{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 2 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic3}
\topictitle{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 3 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic4}
\topictitle{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 4 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic5}
\topictitle{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 5 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_topics_seq
\tl_new:N \g_presentation_title_tl
\iow_new:N \g_output_stream

\NewDocumentCommand{\topictitle}{m}
{
  \__topic_title:n {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__topic_title:n #1
{
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_topics_seq {#1}
}

\AtEndDocument
{
  \tl_gset:Nx \g_presentation_title_tl
  {
    \seq_use:Nn\g_topics_seq {,~}
  }
  \iow_open:Nn \g_output_stream { \c_sys_jobname_str.sbj }
  \iow_now:Nx \g_output_stream { \exp_not:V\g_presentation_title_tl }
  \iow_close:N \g_output_stream
}

\AtEndPreamble{%
  \file_if_exist:nTF {\c_sys_jobname_str.sbj} {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\file_input:n {\c_sys_jobname_str.sbj}}
    \exp_args:NV \title \l_tmpa_tl
  }{
    \title{No topic!}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
%
\input{topic1}
% \input{topic2}
\input{topic3}
% \input{topic4}
\input{topic5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it sounds a bit overdoing to use an extra file for this. Why don't you write to the aux-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree. That is what I tried first but, when I wanted to read the content of the `.aux` file, it was empty (I probably didn't read it at the right moment). IIRC, I also had some difficulties to write both a verbatim text (e.g.`\title{` and `}`) and, inside, the (not expanded: `\exp_not:V`) content of `\g_presentation_title_tl`.

Comment: You don't have to *manually* read the `.aux` file: it is automatically `\input` as part of the work done by `\begin{document}`, [before the `\AtBeginDocument` hooks are run](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120978/73317).

Comment: @frougon Yes, I know that but when I tried to exploit what was in it, it simply didn't exist according to LaTeX's message.

Comment: Proof needed. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply write to the aux-file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic1}
\topictitle{% \TeX{},
 \LaTeX{} and café%
}
\begin{frame}
  \TeX{}, \LaTeX{} and café are nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic2}
\topictitle{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 2 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic3}
\topictitle{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 3 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic4}
\topictitle{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 4 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic5}
\topictitle{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 5 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_topics_seq


\NewDocumentCommand\addtopictitle{m}
{
 \seq_gput_right:Nn\g_topics_seq {#1} 
}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\topictitle}{m}
{
  \iow_now:Nx \@mainaux
   {
    \exp_not:n {\addtopictitle{#1}}
   }
}

\title{\seq_use:Nn\g_topics_seq {,~}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
%
\input{topic1}
% \input{topic2}
\input{topic3}
\input{topic4}
\input{topic5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'd do as Ulrike suggests, writing to the `\@mainaux` to avoid polluting the file streams. I'd also avoid expansion (mainly `x`-type) of the text, as this is likely to cause you trouble.

Note also that in your code the `\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\file_input:n {\c_sys_jobname_str.sbj}}` didn't do anything because `\input` is not expandable, so you ended up with `\title{\input{\jobname.sbj}}`.

The approach I propose is to, at the end of the document, write a `\gdef\@input@topics{<stuff>}` to the `\@mainaux`, which will be read in the next run. After the file is read then the `\@input@topics` is already known and can be simply used in the title. The written definition has to be global because the contents of the `.aux` file are read inside a group.

At the writing step I used `e`-type expansion in `\seq_use:Nn` because `x`-type expansion is too much, and because `f`-type would try to expand the first tokens of the title, which would expand `\TeX` unless there was a space before it. Everything is put in `\exp_not:e` to avoid the `x` expansion of `\write`. An extra `\exp_not:N` is needed before `\@input@topics` for later runs, where it is already defined.

Here's the code:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic1}
\topictitle{\TeX{},
 \LaTeX{} and café%
}
\begin{frame}
  \TeX{}, \LaTeX{} and café are nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic2}
\topictitle{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 2 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic3}
\topictitle{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 3 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic4}
\topictitle{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 4 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{topic5}
\topictitle{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
  Topic 5 is nice!
\end{frame}
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_topics_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\topictitle}{m}
  { \__topic_title:n {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__topic_title:n #1
  { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_topics_seq {#1} }

\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument
  {
    \iow_now:Nx \@auxout
      {
        \gdef \exp_not:N \@input@topics
            { \exp_not:e { \seq_use:Nn \g_topics_seq {,~} } }
      }
  }

\AtBeginDocument
  {
    \cs_if_exist:NTF \@input@topics
      { \exp_args:NV \title \@input@topics }
      { \title { No~topic! } }
  }
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}
%
\input{topic1}
% \input{topic2}
\input{topic3}
% \input{topic4}
\input{topic5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice explanations about expansions, that I still find hard to understand correctly.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Sorry if I couldn't explain it right. You mean the types of expansion (`e`, `f`, `x`)? If so you can take a look at `interface3.pdf` (`texdoc interface3`), section *3 Introducing the variants*.